# How to disable user from ordering from more than one restaurant

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm creating a react native food ordering application. I want to disable the user from ordering from multiple restaurants at the same time. Currently, with using Redux, the user can choose multiple dishes from multiple restaurants. I'm not sure what to search for to find a solution.

For example, in some apps the function/message appears
"Start new order? Your basket with Restaurant X will be cleared."

This is my code for setting up redux reducer.

```
let defaultState = {
selectedItems: { items: [], cafeName: "" },
};

let cartReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case "ADD_TO_CART": {
  let newState = { ...state };

  if (action.payload.checkboxValue) {
    console.log("ADD TO CART");

    newState.selectedItems = {
      items: [...newState.selectedItems.items, action.payload],
      cafeName: action.payload.cafeName,
    };
  } else {
    console.log("REMOVE FROM CART");
    newState.selectedItems = {
      items: [
        ...newState.selectedItems.items.filter(
          (item) => item.name !== action.payload.name
        ),
      ],
      cafeName: action.payload.cafeName,
    };
  }
  console.log(newState);
  return newState;
}

default:
  return state;
```

}
};

Comment: If this app hits any decent size, this validation needs to be done on the server side too.

Comment: Before adding a new item check if it's from a different restaurant. Then show that message. If they want to clear the current items send a CLEAR_AND_ADD action or something like that.

Comment: As far as I can tell you only need a simple if statement to make this work.

Comment: Alternatively you could save the list of items namespaced by the restaurant, and keep an activeRestaurant on state. Then you could switch between lists or even add mutli-order support.